# Search or filter a large data set so it doesn't feel like UI is frozen briefly

Tags: ember.js

I would like to find the best solution for filtering a large data set in Ember as quickly and as smoothly as possible for the user.

Here is an example that does lock up briefly search on a list of 2500 names. For example try do a search starting with 'A'.

http://jsbin.com/ulukep/26/edit

(Bonus points if the solution uses https://github.com/emberjs/list-view)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing that is making it feel slow is not search/filter but actually rendering the results.  Ember list view is a good solution, it's pretty easy to add it to your example.

Add the ember-list-view library and the required css:

```
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/list-view/list-view-latest.js"></script>
<style>
.ember-list-view {
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.ember-list-item-view {
  position: absolute;
}
</style>
```

Replace handlebars `{{each}}` block in your template with ember-list-view, still using `view.filteredList` as the content:

```
{{#collection Ember.ListView contentBinding="view.filteredList" height=100 rowHeight=20 width=500}}
  {{name}}
{{/collection}}
```

Thats it. Now search starting with 'A' returns lightning fast, nothing locks up. Try it here: http://jsbin.com/ulukep/27